# dynamic variable in URLFOR in visualforce page script

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi I am trying place a dynamic variable in

`"{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons,iconname)}"`, script in Visualforce page

iconname is variable declared in script but its not taking.

Can anyone tell how to pass dynamic variable in the above.

Basically I wanted to use it in leaflet maps in vf page

```
L.icon({iconUrl: "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons,iconname)}",iconSize: [60, 60] })
```

Please help.

Comment: Urlfor is resolved during rendering on server side, so, could you please provide more information of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the image, so that i can pass it in icon attribute of Leaflet maps https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: I guess you will have to declare variables for the icons, potentially a map for them, and then use this declared JavaScript map on leaflet with this `iconName`. Or something around those lines.

Comment: I have decalred a variable and got the image name but   
  let iconname = 'testimage.png';
L.icon({iconUrl: "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons,iconname)}",iconSize: [60, 60] }) thats not working

Comment: Yes but what I mean is the other way around, eg: `let iconOne = "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons, 'iconPath')}";` or perhaps a map for these entries. So you can use this on your code such as `L.icon({iconUrl: iconOne, iconSize: [60, 60]})`.

Comment: probelm is declaring the iconPath in URLFOR, which is has to be dynamic. For example let iconPath='testimg'; let iconOne = "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons, 'iconPath')}"; L.icon({iconUrl: iconOne, iconSize: [60, 60]})  iconPath string always changes

Comment: did you try using an `apex:variable` for `iconname`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create an array with each urlfor and use it on your reference to the icon? See below:

Add to your page:

```
var icons = {
  'icon1': "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons, 'icon1')}",
  'icon2': "{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartsIcons, 'icon2')}"
};

...
```

On your reference you can use the indirection:

```
L.icon({iconUrl: icons[iconName], iconSize: [60, 60] })
```

Another option would be to store the path to `$Resource.ChartsIcons` and then append the path but I feel that this might be more fragile - [example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147433/referencing-static-resource-images-in-a-visualforce-page).